# get item from a list of dictionaries via index

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of (ordered) dictionaries where the dictionary contents across the list may share the same keys:

```
list = [{"key1": value1, "key2": value2}, {"key1": value3, "key2": value4}, {"key2": value5, "key3": value6}]
```

Given a 'global' index, I want to extract the relevant key/value pair. For example, given the index `3`, I want to return `"key2": value4`. I can see how to do this with a nested for loop but this operation will be performed many times and the dictionary is quite large, so I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to perform this operation.

Comment: your dictionaries are not ordered, you should use ordereddict for that.

Comment: You should flatten out key-value pairs into an ordered list & use that for indexing. Order does not make sense in dictionaries

Comment: In recent versions of python, dicts are ordered by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way extracting the `dict.items` and flattening with [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

```
from itertools import chain
l = [{"key1": 'value1', "key2": 'value2'}, {"key1": 'value3', "key2": 'value4'}, {"key2": 'value5', "key3": 'value6'}]

index = 3
dict([list(chain.from_iterable(map(dict.items, l)))[index]])
# {'key2': 'value4'}
```

Do note that for python versions older than `3.6` insertion order in dictionaries is not kept.

What you could do in that case is to define your dictionaries as `OrderedDict`s and then do the same as above but mapping with `OrderedDict.items` instead.

Also as a side note, don't name your lists `list`, it masks the built-in name.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `itertools.chian.from_iterable` with `itertools.islice`:

```
from itertools import chain, islice
my_list = [{"key1": 'value1', "key2": 'value2'}, {"key1": 'value3', "key2": 'value4'}, {"key2": 'value5', "key3": 'value6'}]

index = 3
next(islice(chain.from_iterable(map(dict.items, my_list )), index, index + 1))
```

output:

```
('key2', 'value4')
```

this will boost your performance if you have a large list of dictionaries

---

for example if you have 10_000 times more dictionaries in your list:

```
my_list = [{"key1": 'value1', "key2": 'value2'}, {"key1": 'value3', "key2": 'value4'}, {"key2": 'value5', "key3": 'value6'}] * 10000
index=3

# @yatu approach
%timeit dict([list(chain.from_iterable(map(dict.items, my_list)))[index]])
# 14.9 ms ± 1.01 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

#using itertools.islice
%timeit next(islice(chain.from_iterable(map(dict.items, my_list )), index, index + 1))
# 1.87 µs ± 63.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

by using `itertools.islice` you will get  approx x7967 times faster runtime for `index=3`